# How can I group contents of fields, when contents contain multiple items?

Tags: php

I have a table called 'products' with a field/column called 'features'. The features are comma delimited. So pulling several rows would result in something like this for each...

```
11,40,51,68
```

and another might look like this...

```
11,31,37,50
```

I want to be able to show each number as a result, but result '11' is common between the 2 fields. So I only want 11 to show up once. In other words, no duplicates.

I'm really not even sure where to begin here...

```
$query="SELECT features FROM products WHERE ???";
list($xxxx)=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query))
```

How can I query this to not display the duplicates, and give me one entry per number-group?

Comment: do it properly and make another table for `features`. one feature = one row with feature number and `product_ID` foreign key

Comment: Hi Peter. I have another table with all the features. That's why I need these "feature ID's" listed so I can get the feature name. Hope that explains my train of thought.

Comment: Yeah so you need 3rd table "product_features" where you can connect product with features. `PRODUCTS: product_id,product_name,etc.`, `FEATURES: feature_id,feature_name,etc.`, `PRODUCT_FEATURES: product_feature_id,product_id,feature_id` with unique key for `product_id,feature_id`

Comment: oh wow. I see. Seems I am way off here. Ok thank you very much. I will see about adding a 3rd table to reference products and features. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Do it properly. You need additional table:

Table "Products":

> ```
> product_id
> product_name
> product_price
> ... extra fields
> ```

Table "Features":

> ```
> feature_id
> feature_name
> ... extra fields
> ```

Table "Product_features": (you need this table)

> ```
> product_feature_id
> product_id
> feature_id
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT features FROM products");
$features = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $features = array_merge($features, explode(',', $row->features));
}
$features = array_unique($features);
print_r($features);
```

If you have the chance, @Peter answer is the best option.

Comment: Thanks Edakos. This is printing all the numbers for each field. I am trying to get one list for all, without duplicates.